# Number of subsets of length 7

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have the following summation:
$$\sum\limits_{k=7}^{n}  {k-1\choose 6} $$
and apparently it counts the number of subsets of {1, 2, . . . , n} having size 7.

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably know that ${n\choose 7}$ is the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of size $7$.

Each such subset has a largest element. The largest element must be one of $7,8,\ldots,n$. For each possible largest element, let's count the number of subsets having that as a largest element. We already chose the largest, so there are $6$ elements left to choose. So we add all the subsets of size $7$ with the largest element $7$: choose $6$ elements from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, that is ${6\choose 6}$. Then the largest element $8$: that is ${7\choose 6}$, and so on.

The final count of the subsets is

$${6\choose 6}+{7\choose 6}+\cdots +{n-1\choose 6}$$
$$=\sum_{k=7}^{n}  {k-1\choose 6}$$

which is therefore equal to

$${n\choose 7}$$

Comment: I like your solution better than mine.  It gives intuition and is not overly mechanical (like mine).  Kudos.

Comment: @TravisJ: Thanks for the encouragement! Your answer is also nice: I like knowing both kinds of proof for combinatorial identities.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of Pascal's recurrence.  The recurrence is that $\binom{i}{j}+\binom{i}{j-1} = \binom{i+1}{j}$ provided that $0< j\leq i$.

\begin{align*}
\binom{6}{6}+\binom{7}{6} &= \binom{7}{7} + \binom{7}{6} \\
                          &= \binom{8}{7} \\
\binom{6}{6}+\binom{7}{6} + \binom{8}{6} &= \binom{8}{7} + \binom{8}{6} \\
                          &= \binom{9}{7} \\
\binom{6}{6} + \binom{7}{6} + \binom{8}{6} + \binom{9}{6} &= \binom{9}{7} + \binom{9}{6} \\
&= \binom{10}{7}
\end{align*}
This process repeats until you get to $\binom{n-1}{6}+\binom{n-1}{7}=\binom{n}{7}$.  It helps to draw Pascal's Triangle and follow the additions down the tree...